# How to select geometry column to use in Create Database View tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, sql-view

I have a geodatabase locally and when I try to do simple query using Create Database View like:

```
SELECT   Name, sum(Area) as Areaa, Shape
FROM     houses
GROUP BY Name, Shape,Area
```

[image]

it returns that the column shape does not exist but in reality its my geometry column.

[image]

I would like to create a view with geometry but the tool returns a table only.

How can I get my result with spatial representation?

Comment: That is not a valid SQL statement. The GROUP BY requires grouped results, but the `shape` column is ungrouped. Please [Edit] the question to specify the RDBMS in use.

Comment: question is updated

Comment: It's still invalid SQL. Plus, file geodatabase isn't an RDBMS. The command doc states (my emphasis) "Creates a view **in a database** based on an SQL expression." You also ought to name the `sum(Area)` field with `AS` {alias}.

Comment: As can be seen, i corrected my sql but the error is still appearing. Could someone help me with that please

Comment: `GROUP BY shape` isn't valid in most of the databases I've used (at least, it's unlikely to return valid results). "Geodatabase locally" isn't a clear distinction on the RDBMS product in use.

Comment: SO what shall i do to get the desired output?

Comment: It depends on the RDBMS in use.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412693/how-to-select-geometry-column-to-use-in-create-database-view-tool-in-arcgis-pro#comment670748_412693):

> ... file geodatabase isn't an RDBMS. The command doc states (my
> emphasis) "Creates a view **in a database** based on an SQL
> expression."

My understanding was that you are trying to use a tool designed for an RDBMS with a file geodatabase, which is not an RDBMS, but @user1974 has clarified that in [their comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412693/how-to-select-geometry-column-to-use-in-create-database-view-tool-in-arcgis-pro/414300?noredirect=1#comment729237_414300):

> To clarify, it ***is*** possible to create a database view in a file
> geodatabase:  [Create Database View (Data
> Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-database-view.htm):
> “This tool is supported for databases, enterprise geodatabases, mobile
> geodatabases, and **file geodatabases**.” But just a heads up: there
> is a bug where we can't use the `/` character in the SQL when using
> that tool.
> https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/loss-of-division-when-creating-a-database-view-in/td-p/1106057